# call a model from a command class in Laravel 5, and pass the command class itself

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I have a laravel 5.5 `artisan` command working, so of course I can use methods like `$this->info()` and `$this->arguments()` etc..  it looks like this:

```
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Compasspointmedia\Julietmenu\Model\Menu;

class MenuManagementCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The console command name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'julietmenu:menu 
    {action=list}';

    protected $description = 'Manages menu elements per the Juliet CMS specification';

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        //trying to make this command methods available in Menu
        $this->menu = new Menu($this);
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // this works just fine
        $this->info('Calling ' . $this->argument('action'));

        $action = $this->argument('action');
        $this->menu->action();    
    }
}
```

Of course, I would like do the actual work in the `Model`, not the command, using the command like a controller.  Here's the model class so far:

```
namespace Compasspointmedia\Julietmenu\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Menu extends Model {
    //
    public function __construct($command){
        $this->command = $command;
        // this says the `arguments` method is present:
        print_r(get_class_methods($this->command));

        // but, it does not work!
        // error: "Call to a member function getArguments() on null"
        $this->arguments = $this->command->arguments();
    }

    public function node(){
        echo '--- it works! -----';
    }
}
```

To the point, how do I pass the `Command` object to the Model so that I can use `$this->command->arguments()` or the other Command features inside the model?

P.S. I'd be very grateful to know if there's a native "Laravel way" to do this better than passing the entire `$this` to a constructor.

Comment: Why would you not just do it in the Command class? That's what it's there for, i.e. the native laravel way!

Comment: You probably have a point, but this will be a very diverse command, and some sub-commands might require interacting with questions, so that means that if I flip it around and have the command call the model for finite tasks, all parameters need to be got by the command in the first place.  Haha, perhaps that's the Inversion of Control I'm looking for ;)

Comment: You could always have a main command that than triggers other commands based on the arguments passed, but at way, all your login is in Command Classes instead of Models. Laravel lets you call Command classes from other commands.